# Check if a random number is multiple of 8 (python)

Tags: python, math

I am just starting to learn Python, and I want to find out if a random number is a multiple of 8, tried it but failed horribly...  Struggled with math in school and trying to pick it up as I go. :/

Look around everywhere, found answers for C but not Python

**Code**

```
import random

Numbers = [15, 100, 50, 70, 5, 10, 12, 20, 123, 72, 81, 76, 25, 19, 40, 17, 16, 32]

print("\n\n")

def getRandomSelection(numbers):
  one = (random.choice(numbers))
  two = (random.choice(numbers))
  if two == one:
    while two == one:
      two = (random.choice(Numbers))

return one, two

print("\n\n")

def MutipleOfEight(numList):

  one = int(getRandomSelection(Numbers))
  print("First Number: " + str(one))
  if (one % 8 == 0): #To check if it's multiple of 8
    print(str(one) + "is a multiple of 8")
  else:
    print(str(one) + "is not a multiple of 8")
```

It gets the numbers and returns them, tested it on simple maths functions, just don't get how to do multiples...  Would appreciate any help! :)

And yes, I googled how to find multiples, but I still don't get it. :/

Comment: Using the modulo operator is the right approach - what exactly is not working?

Comment: With `return one, two` you return a tuple containing two values. Then you try to convert this tuple to an integer with `int(getRandomSelection(Numbers))`. That won't work. BTW, you're not even calling any of your functions.

Comment: 1. Python syntax: `Why is my code not working? Why is my code failing? Why is my computer on fire?` This is usually resolved by carefully reading through the language documentation. You need to make sure that you are using/returning correct data types. Notice that you are returning two values from the `getRandomSelection`. Python assumes that you need to return a tuple, and that exactly what it does.
2. Python semantic: These are usually logic problems, that don't fail, but produce incorrect results. Notice that in `MultipleOfEight` you are taking `numList`, but never using it!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
You haven't described a specific problem; you haven't provided the failing output; the code is almost certainly not minimal to cause the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues here;

- The return statement is not at the correct scope, you should be returning the value from the method call, as it stands the return is in the main body. ( this may have become an issue while posting to StackOverflow )
- You cast your return value to an `int`

In your method definition, you return a `tuple`:

```
return one, two
```

But when fetching the value, you cast it to an `int`

```
one = int(getRandomSelection(Numbers))
```

Instead, actually fetch the `tuple`:

```
( one, two ) = getRandomSelection(Numbers)
```

- Your `MutipleOfEight` definition takes a list of numbers, but that is not the list that you actually use:

  def MutipleOfEight(numList):
     one = int(getRandomSelection(Numbers))

Should become:

```
 def MutipleOfEight(numList):
   ( one, two ) = getRandomSelection(numList)
```

Finally, you never actually invoke your main method; at the end of your script; add this line to actually run it:

```
MultipleOfEight(Numbers)
```

Call this method using *Numbers*, the master list you have defined at the top.

Answer (score 1):

`getRandomSelection` returns a tuple of two numbers, so the `int(getRandomSelection(Numbers))` fails. You could just do `one, two = getRandomSelection(Numbers)`, without converting to `int`. The math you have looks correct though.

Answer (score 0):

The others have already pointed out the mistakes so I remade the code for you if you want to take a look.

```
import random

Numbers = [15, 100, 50, 70, 5, 10, 12, 20, 123, 72, 81, 76, 25, 19, 40, 17, 16, 32]

def getRandomSelection(numbersList):
  one = (random.choice(numbersList))
  two = (random.choice(numbersList))
  while two == one:
    two = (random.choice(numbersList))

  return one, two

def MutipleOfEight(numbersList):
  one,two = getRandomSelection(numbersList) # You can use this to get both numbers from the other function
  print("First Number: " + str(one))
  if (one % 8 == 0): #To check if it's multiple of 8
    print(str(one) + " is a multiple of 8")
  else:
    print(str(one) + " is not a multiple of 8")

  print("\n\n")

  print("Second Number: " + str(two))
  if (two % 8 == 0): #To check if it's multiple of 8
    print(str(two) + " is a multiple of 8")
  else:
    print(str(two) + " is not a multiple of 8")

MutipleOfEight(Numbers)
```